# a color histogram algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i'm trying to write the code of an article which name is *VSUMM*.
but i'm stopped in one step of coding and i do not know if i'm write or not!?
acoording to Article:
*In VSUMM, the color histogram algorithm is applied to the HSV color space, which is a popular choice for manipulating color.The HSV color space was developed to provide an intuitive representation of color and to be near to the way in which humans perceive 
and manipulate color. The VSUMM color histogram is computed only from the Hue component, which represents the dominant spectral component color in its pure form (Manjunath
et al., 2001). Moreover, the quantization of the color histogram is set to 16 color bins, aiming at reducing significantly the amount of data without loosing important information. The color bins value was established through experimental tests (see Avila et al., 2008b).*
for this step i've done this,is it correct:

```
b=imread('pics\1.jpeg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(b);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
```

Comment: `h` is the hue channel, so if that's what you're after then yes, it is correct.

Comment: my English is not that good. i read the article(the italic part) and i've done this,but i'm asking myself again and again if i understand the text well enough or not? so the code is correct?

Comment: Yes it looks right. Now you can find a histogram of `h` by doing something like `hist(h,16)`

Comment: thanks a lot,i can't appreciate well enough,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks good. However, use [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) instead of `hist`.