# calculate Euclidean distance of two image in hsv color space in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hsv, euclidean-distance

i use the code below to calculate the Euclidean distance for two rgb images:

```
Im1 = imread(filename1);
Im1 = rgb2gray(Im1);
hn1 = imhist(Im1)./numel(Im1);
Im2 = imread(filename2);
Im2 = rgb2gray(Im2);
hn2 = imhist(Im2)./numel(Im2);
 f = norm(hn1-hn2);
```

and it gives me the correct answer
but now i want to use the code for two images in hsv color mode but it wont work on it
cause all of the above code is in a 2d space while hsv is 1d
is there any specific code for calculating  Euclidean distance of two image in hsv color space?
the images format are jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a histogram for each channel seperatetly

```
function hst = im2hsvHist( img )
% 
% computes three channels histogram in HSV color space
%
n = 256; % number of bins per hist (per channel)
hsvImg = rgb2hsv( img );
hst = zeros(n,3);
for ci = 1:3 
    hst(:,ci) = imhist( hsvImg(:,:,ci ) , n );
end
hst = hst(:) ./ n; % to 3*n vector, normalize by n and not 3n
```

Using this function you can compute the image to image distance in hsv space

```
Im1 = imread(filename1);
hst1 = im2hsvHist(Im1);
Im2 = imread(filename2);
hst2 = im2hsvDist(Im2);
f = norm( hst1 - hst2 );
```

Sneak a peek for a vectorized version of `im2hsvHist`:

> n = 256;
>   hsvImg = rgb2hsv( img );
>   hst = hist( reshape(hsvImg, [], 3), 255 ); % instead of loop!
>   hst = hst(:) / n;

Comment: thanks a lot. that's so helpful. can i ask another question about the first part ((im2hsvHist)). i've got images in rgb i convert them to hsv by the code which i mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724689/a-color-histogram-algorithm-in-matlab       does im2hsvHist do the same thing? thank you again

Comment: @samdean - both solutions uses `rgb2hsv` to convert the rgb color space to hsv color space. The question you mensioned uses only the "Hue" channel of the hsv color space. This is equivalent to running the `ci` loop in my function `im2hsvHist` only for `ci=1` - the Hue channel.

Comment: @samdean welcome to stackoverflow. It is customery here to "accept" an answer in case it actually answers your question. You "accept" an answer by clicking the "V" icon beside it. Consider doing so also for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724689/a-color-histogram-algorithm-in-matlab you mentioned before.

Comment: sorry,i'm a little naive in this. so it's ok if i use your code instead of mine cause i thing it's better. and about 256 which is number of bins per hist (per channel) as you saw in the article i'm trying to write its code it mentioned the quantization of the color histogram is set to 16 color bins so should i set 16 to n or it's irrelevant? thanks

Comment: i know i should press the v button and i will. but i think if i press that the question will be locked and i can't ask my question(i.e the comment above) from you. i want to ask this last question and then press the v. am i right about a question get locked after pressing v or not?

Comment: @samdean "accepting" does not affect the question - people can still comment/edit or add new answers.

Comment: @samdean changing `n` to 16 will result with histograms with only 16 bins. But be careful about it: you must have all the bins identical (same centers and widths) see the documentation on how to achieve that.