# Image similarity by Euclidean distance in hsv color space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hsv, euclidean-distance

The code included below calculates the Euclidean distance between two images in hsv color space and if the result is under a Threshold (here set to 0.5) the two images are similar and it will group them in one cluster.

This will be done for a group of images (video frames actually).

It worked well on a group of sample images but when I change the sample it starts to work odd, e.g the result is low for two different images and high (like 1.2) for two similar images.

***For example the result for these two very similar images is relatively high:*** [first pic](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zylz7o&s=5) and [second pic](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h51t07&s=5) when it actually should be under 0.5.

What is wrong?

In the code below, `f` is divided by `100` to allow comparison to values near `0.5`.

```
Im1 = imread('1.jpeg');
Im2 = imread('2.jpeg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(Im1);
hn1 = hsv(:,:,1);
hn1=hist(hn1,16);
hn1=norm(hn1);
hsv = rgb2hsv(Im2);
hn2 = hsv(:,:,1);
hn2=hist(hn2,16);
hn2=norm(hn2);
f = norm(hn1-hn2,1)
f=f/100
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17782223/2065121) help?

Comment: i tried that, it did not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```
hn1=hist(hn1,16);
hn1=norm(hn1);
```

convert your 2D image into a scalar.  I suspect that is not what you're interested in doing.....

EDIT:

Probably a better approach would be:

```
hn1 = hist(hn1(:),16) / numel(hn1(:));
```

but, you haven't really given us much on the math, so this is just a guess.

Comment: i've change the code with this and i think it gets better,am i right? i change the hn1=norm(hn1) with hn1 = hn1/norm(hn1); and then f=norm(hn1-hn2)